# Reading a 32bit dll file in IDL 64bit

Tags: idl

I have a 32bit dll file that I want IDL 64bit version to read,

But i get an error trying to do that,

How can I do that?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have the solution for this using IDL_IDLBridge

Please read these commands:

http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/IDL_IDLBridge.html

http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/IDL_IDLBridge__GetVar.html

http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/IDL_IDLBridge__SetVar.html

It works great for me